# How can I hide a "java desktop application"

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application

I'm newbie in Java so I deicide make an application use "java desktop application" in Netbeans. It creates 3 file (`ProjectNameAboutBox.java` (JFrame Form), `ProjectNameApp.java`, `ProjectNameView.java` (JFrame Form and all my code in this file)).

Now, I want to ask how can I hide and restore this application when run? I already made a systemTray for it

Thank you

Comment: it is usual that an answer that has worked is accepted by the author of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `frame.setVisible(false)` to hide and `frame.setVisible(true)` to show.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I knew setVisible but I don't know what will be setVisible in this case. Could you explain more?

Comment: I think it's better if you can trial on that feature of Netbeans. Because I still can't find out what are JFrame needed to setVisible. I only add more textfield, textarea and button to my application

Comment: Your class is a JFrame (it extends a JFrame). call `setVisible(false)`